# C language - operation replaces mutiple array elements instead of one

Tags: c, arrays, replace

I am in the process of creating hangman in C language, but there is one problem that I cannot quite grasp. When a user correctly guesses one of the letters that the word that is being guessed has, the program replaces all of previously guessed letters to the one user just put. What is the source of this problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int x = 0, isCompleted, matchFound, numberOfTries = 7;
  char letterGuess[1];
  int randomIndex = rand()%14; 
  const char *wordArray[14];
  const char *guessedWord[10];
  const char *usedLetters[17];
  for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    guessedWord[k] = "_";
  }
  wordArray[0] = "butonierka";
  wordArray[1] = "centyfolia";
  wordArray[2] = "chiroplast";
  wordArray[3] = "cmentarzyk";
  wordArray[4] = "chrustniak";
  wordArray[5] = "budowniczy";
  wordArray[6] = "cholewkarz";
  wordArray[7] = "cornflakes";
  wordArray[8] = "brzydactwo";
  wordArray[9] = "germanofil";
  wordArray[10] = "lichtarzyk";
  wordArray[11] = "lutowniczy";
  wordArray[12] = "mikrocysta";
  wordArray[13] = "tryskawiec";

  const char *wordToGuess = wordArray[randomIndex];

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf(" %s ", guessedWord[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");

  while(numberOfTries != 0 && isCompleted != 10) {
    matchFound = 0;
    isCompleted = 0;
    printf("Please give a lowercase letter\n");
    printf("Left tries: %d\n", numberOfTries);
    scanf("%s", &letterGuess);
    for (int z = 0; z < 17; z++) {
      if (usedLetters[z] == letterGuess[0]) {
        matchFound = 1;
      }
    }
    if (letterGuess[0] >= 'a' && letterGuess[0] <= 'z' && matchFound == 0) {
      usedLetters[x] = letterGuess[0];
      x++;
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (letterGuess[0] == wordArray[randomIndex][j])
          guessedWord[j] = letterGuess;
          matchFound = 1;
        }
      }
      if (matchFound == 0) {
        numberOfTries--;
      }
      for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
         printf(" %s ", guessedWord[z]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    } else {
      if (matchFound == 1) {
        printf("You've already given such letter!!\n");
      } else {
        printf("Wrong input, please try again!\n"); 
      }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) { 
      if (guessedWord[k] != "_") {
       isCompleted++;
      }
    }
    if (isCompleted == 10) {
      printf("You have correctly guessed a word! Congrats!!\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
  }

  printf("The word was: %s\n", wordArray[randomIndex]);
  printf("Game over!!\n");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: Note: `isCompleted` is not initialized. It could be 10 at the first iteration.

Comment: Your code does not compile. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Where exactly? I am setting its value to 0 after each while loop. I see no way of it getting to 10 at the first iteration.

Comment: What about before the first while loop?

Comment: Your program is too complex, you should restart from scratch with clear algorithm in mind, you have too many loop, too many variable... use function ! Rework your conception.

Comment: You must initialize `isCompleted` _before_ the while loop too. it is an automatic variable that is not initialized unless you do so. So at the first iteration of the while loop it will have any value and can already be 10.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're storing `letterGuess`, rather than individual characters.  So each time `letterGuess` is updated with a new guess, all references to it change.  Also, `letterGuess` is too short, leaving no room for the terminating null character.

The best solution is to make `letterGuess` a `char` (or an `int`), not an array, and to make `guessedWord` a `char []` rather than a `char *[]`.  There is no reason to use strings for single characters.  That will solve the string-sharing problem.